# Why can't I include RestSharp in my Unity project?

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, restsharp

I'm trying to use the code given by Postman to connect an API to my Unity project. The code uses RestSharp. I regenerated Embeded packages and Local packages project files.
[link to Unity/Preferences/External Tools/Generate .csproj files for:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssGly.png) then installed RestSharp version 107.3.0 using NuGet package manager extension on Visual Studio Code. Then used dotnet restore because NuGet told me to. Now my "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" file has:

```
<PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="107.3.0"/>
```

But still, whenever I try to add:

```
using RestSharp;
```

line to my APITest.cs script, Unity says:

```
APITest.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What can I do to use RestSharp with Unity?

Comment: `installed RestSharp version 107.3.0 using NuGet package manager extension on Visual Studio Code` I would say that is why. Rather use e.g. [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) and install it there which makes sure it is actually installed into your Unity project as a [Plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add projects to Unity via NuGet. Any changes to a `.csproj` file inside Unity will get overwritten the next time Unity auto-generates it. Unity doesn't actually use those `.csproj` files the same way a "normal" C# installation does -- it just generates them so that IDEs have an easier time understanding the code.

There are several different ways to add a package to a Unity project:

- Use the built-in [Unity Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html) for official Unity packages
- Import via the [Unity Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/)
- [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) (as per @derHugo's comment)
- [OpenUPM](https://openupm.com/)
- Adding the C# files directly to your project under `Assets` sometimes works as well.

Comment: Thanks to you, I've made RestSharp work by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRn49ehm_pI&ab_channel=MohammadFaizanKhan